# PIC programming in Assembly

Tags: pic, microchip, assembly

I went through an assembly program of the PIC16F88 downloaded from microchip and saw something that I have ever seen before

```
; eeprom definitions

    org 0x2100
    de  LOW(IREF_ZERO), HIGH(IREF_ZERO)
    de  LOW(MAX_BATTERY_VOLTAGE), HIGH(MAX_BATTERY_VOLTAGE)

********End of the program****
```

The **de** does not appear in the set of the instruction the PIC, what does the instructioin **de** do in the program ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

de is an **assembler directive** to declare an EEPROM data byte. org is also a directive.

You can find a full list of assembler directives in the [MPASM manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/33014j.pdf) (see 4.17 for de).

In general all assemblers will have directives of this kind, that don't map to machine language instructions, but the syntax varies between assemblers.